The Graphics2D.drawImage() method works, but the image doesn't appear on the panel
I'm trying to draw an image on this panel for a game similar to Window Kill. Using the System.out.println() method, it seems the image is being drawn, and I call the repaint() method in the thread. However, the image doesn't appear when I run the program.
package org.example.View.GamePagePanels;

import org.example.Controller;
import org.example.Location;
import org.example.View.BossHeadView;
import org.example.View.EntityView;
import org.example.View.EpsilonView;
import org.example.movement.EpsilonKeylistener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BossHeadPanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean Isometric=false;
    private boolean isRigid=false;
    private String ID="";
    public Thread thread;

    public boolean isIsometric() {
        return Isometric;
    }

    public void setIsometric(boolean isometric) {
        Isometric = isometric;
    }

    public boolean isRigid() {
        return isRigid;
    }

    public void setRigid(boolean rigid) {
        isRigid = rigid;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    JLabel smiley;
    Image image;

    public BossHeadPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        ID= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        setLayout(null);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(EpsilonKeylistener.getEpsilonKeylistener());
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/icons/boss.png");
        image= icon.getImage();
        smiley=new JLabel();
        smiley.setIcon(icon);
        smiley.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        smiley.setVisible(true);
        this.add(smiley);

        //


        thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (Controller.isRunning){
//                    System.out.println("entity size: "+EntityView.entityViews.size());
                    ArrayList<EntityView> entities=EntityView.entityViews;
                    for(int i=0;i< entities.size();i++){
                        EntityView ent=entities.get(i);
                        if(isShowing()){
                            if ((ent.location.getX()>=getLocationOnScreen().getX() && ent.location.getX()<=getLocationOnScreen().getX()+getWidth() )||
                                    ( ent.location.getY()>= getLocationOnScreen().getY() && ent.location.getY()<=getLocationOnScreen().getY()+getHeight())){
                                double x=ent.location.getX()-getLocationOnScreen().getX();
                                double y=ent.location.getY()-getLocationOnScreen().getY();
                                ent.panelLocations.put(getID(),new Location(x,y));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if(isShowing()){
                        if((EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getX()>=getLocationOnScreen().getX() && EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getX()<=getLocationOnScreen().getX()+getWidth() )||
                                ( EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getY()>= getLocationOnScreen().getY() && EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getY()<=getLocationOnScreen().getY()+getHeight())){
                            double x=EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getX()-getLocationOnScreen().getX();
                            double y=EpsilonView.getEpsilonView().getY()-getLocationOnScreen().getY();
                            EpsilonView.epsilonView.panelLocations.put(getID(),new Location(x,y));
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
//        System.out.println("paint component");
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.fillOval(0,0,20,20);

        if(image!=null){
            g2.drawImage(image,0,0,100,100,this);
            System.out.println("image drawing");
        }else{
            System.out.println("the image doean'e load");
        }


    }
//    protected void paint_Boss(Graphics2D g2){
//        for(int i=0;i<BossHeadView.Boss.size();i++) {
//            BossHeadView boss = BossHeadView.Boss.get(i);
//        }
//    }
}

I also tried filling an oval in the paintComponent() method to see if other methods work, and the oval is drawn without any issues. I also tried adding the image using a JLabel, but it didn't work either

image!=null is not helpful for how the image is being loaded - new ImageIcon() will create a pseudo-image (empty) if the file is not found - use ImageIO to read the image (or, not recommended, use image.getHeight() or image.getWidth(), which returns -1 if the image was not loaded) || the image should not be loaded from src - that directory is not intended to be deployed and most probably is not being found in actual execution; strongly recommended to use getResource() from ClassLoader

for example see Loading resources using getClass().getResource() , JFrame not showing a picture , and probably many more

You are calling method repaint() in a thread which is not the EDT

Shouldn't your override of paintComponent be public instead of protected?

@Just another Java programmer: The JComponent paintComponent method is protected.  You can override it as public, but you can override it as protected as well.

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer when overriding you may increase the visibility of a visible method but you can't reduce it.  So it works since paintComponent is declared as protected.
